# Django can't serialize Object because of _id prefix

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm making a program which allows my frontend to send a Question Number and Category name to receive a question from the database.

However, When i go to serialize the question object to send it back, the serializer errors.

**Model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Category(models.Model): #Might Change later
    CategoryTitle = models.TextField()

class Question(models.Model):
    questionText = models.TextField()
    QuestionType = models.TextField()
    questionScore = models.IntegerField()
    QuestionNist = models.TextField()
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import(Question)

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id','questionText','QuestionType','questionScore','Category')
```

View.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import (Category, Question)
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .serializers import (QuestionSerializer, QuestionSender)
from rest_framework.response import Response as Rs

class questionRecive(APIView):
    QuestionSerializer = QuestionSerializer
    QuestionSender = QuestionSender

 def get(self, request):
    user = self.authcall(request)
    QuestionSenderInstance = self.QuestionSender(data=request.data)
    
    print(request.data)
    if QuestionSenderInstance.is_valid():
        print(QuestionSenderInstance.validated_data.get('Category'))
        CategoryRequested=QuestionSenderInstance.validated_data.get('Category')
        try:
            CategoryID = Category.objects.get(CategoryTitle=CategoryRequested)
        except:
            Response = HttpResponse("Invalid Category", content_type="text/plain")
            return Response

        try:
            QuestionObject = Question.objects.filter(Category=CategoryID).values()
            print(QuestionObject)
        except:
            Response = HttpResponse("No QUestions Within Category", content_type="text/plain")
            return Response


        questionnumber = QuestionSenderInstance.validated_data.get('QuestionNumber')
        print(questionnumber)
        SelectedQuestion = QuestionObject[questionnumber]
        print(f'{SelectedQuestion} HERE')
        SerializedQuestion = self.QuestionSerializer(data=SelectedQuestion)
        if SerializedQuestion.is_valid():
            print(SerializedQuestion.data)
            return Rs(SerializedQuestion.data)
        else:
            response = HttpResponse('Invalid Data')
            return response
    else:
        Response = HttpResponse('Invalid Data')
        return Response
```

The seralizer then errors with:

```
'Category': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

This i believe is because the Model field is called Category however, the object seems to have a 'Category_id' attribute. Any idea how to remove the prefix or otherwise fix the problem

My Reasoning for this is that my Question objects look like this:

```
{'id': 1, 'questionText': 'kmkk', 'QuestionType': 'mmkk', 'questionScore': 1, 'QuestionNist': 'aflmlfl', 'Category_id': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong with this ?

```
fields = ('_id','questionText','QuestionType','questionScore','Category')
```

notice the: `_id`

Comment: i guess you are using mongo db

Comment: Not Sure you quite understand the question, check my recent edit (i didn't give enough info)